# I want to Disable the particular place for RecyclerTouchListener @onClick because I've button in that place and button.onClickListener also

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a  RecyclerViewClickListener.RecyclerTouchListener and on that @onClick override method, I sat Intent to go another activity.
But the problem is on that RecyclerViewClickListener.RecyclerTouchListener there is one image view also and I implemented onClickListener of that InmageView so that it will open one dialog box.

Now, when I click on that ImageView, 2 things happened at same time.
1.Opened Dialog box
2.It is going to another activity also, because of Intent.

How can I fix?

Comment: Add some code so we can help you

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I've added boy! Please please help na

Comment: Add code for `OnClickListener` of `ImageView` where you call `onClickHamburger` of callback.

Comment: @Ranjan Please see the updated question/code and help me boy

Comment: Let me clarify. You want to move to an activity when you clicked on the image, or you want to open the dialog?

Comment: @Ranjan Not working your solution.

Comment: @Malv When I click on Image, it must should open dialog box, but not move to an activity at same time (because currently it is happening), but when I don' click on Image view, but click somewhere else on RecyclerView it should move to an activity and not open dialog box.

Comment: @Malv In short, when I click on Image, it should only open dialog box. When I not click on Image, but click somewhere else on RecyclerTouchListener onClick, it should move to an acitivty (not open dialog box)

Comment: @Malv chk cmnt boy

Comment: @Malv I'm confused

Comment: @Ranjan can you please help?

Comment: @Malv  can you please help?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul can you please help?

Comment: @Malv where can I define View.OnClickListener onClickListener = ew View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: @Malv Hello boy?

Comment: The `onClickListener` you define can be anywhere like where you `setAdapter`. Just add it before it and pass it to adapter constructor.

Comment: @Malv I'm inflating the row in adapter, then how it can be anywhere? Am I doing something wrong? Please help –

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155065/how-is-it-possible-to-know-which-view-has-clicked-in-a-layout-onclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
holder.hamburgerMenu.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (menuInterface != null) {
                menuInterface.onClickHamburger(position);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Rajan it is not working. When I click on that Image, it is not opening Dialog box! should I've to do something else on activity, where call back is coming?